# using motion to trigger snapshot when movement stops

Tags: camera, snapshot, motion

I am trying to use motion software (but I could use just any other linux software) in order to "log" some manual work by snapshots. So imagine I want to make a stop-motion film with my LEGO(r) toys (just an example, but for better understanding), and my webcam should take one snapshot when my hands get out of the way. There are tons of docs in the Internet to achieve the opposite (record when move detected), but none this way:

1. wait until there is movement in the field of view
2. detect movement, so wait until movement stops
3. movement stops, so take an snapshot.

Is this possible with motion, cheese, or other webcam software?